# Scope - ye demisse of ye yorne

Tags: discussion, scope

This is a scoping question.  I'd like to ask a question that initially seems like something more suitable for ELU, but is really about the history of printing.

Specifically, whether/how early printers (specifically German) contributed to English abandoning the letter [thorn (Þ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)) for voiced and unvoiced *th*: Initially replaced with *y*, (thus we get *ye olde Historie Stack*) and eventually with just *th*.   I also want to ask about whether early English printers might have cast their own type (e.g. thorn blocks).

Is such a question appropriate here? If not, what's your best guess for whether it's better for ELU, or somewhere else?

Comment: **I** like it, FWIW. I'm not sure how ELU would feel about it.

Comment: The Wikipedia article implies, that other than for the words 'the' (þe) and 'that' (þt), the letter was not often used. It then states: `One major reason for this was that Y existed in the printer's type fonts that were imported from Germany or Italy, while Þ did not.` The 1879 book on pages 47 and 48 also states that the printers often weren't English and simply replaced the unknown letter. [Changes In The English Language: Between The Publication Of Wiclif's Bible And That Of The Authorised Version. A.d. 1400 To A.d. 1600](https://books.google.com/books?id=0xEFAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA47)

Comment: @MarkJohnson Something that can be addressed when/if the actual question is posted.

Comment: Did the proposed question ever get asked?  If so, an answer here with a link to it here would be nice.

Comment: @RayButterworth As so often happens,  the question answered itself (as much as it could) during research.

Comment: @Spencer, if you mean Mark Johnson's comment, remember that comments can disappear without notice at any time.

Comment: @RayButterworth Much more than that comment. Anyway, the fact that Mark answered a question that hadn't been asked yet in a comment indicates that he thinks it's trivial. So the problem becomes formulating a question that won't be closed as such

Answer (score 8):

This looks like it touches on cultural and miscellaneous historical issues in addition to the purely linguistic ones - and thus seems like a good fit for this site.